# how to write a python code to display magic square matrix according to user input?

Tags: python, math, matrix

This is a program to print a matrix whose sum of each row , column or diagonal elements are equal.
I have a working code but my program gives same output each time i run it. I need a program to print different matrix output for same input.

```
def matrix(n): 
    m = [[0 for x in range(n)]for y in range(n)]
    i = n // 2
    j = n - 1
    num = 1
    while num <= (n * n): 
        if i == -1 and j == n:
            j = n - 2
            i = 0
        else:
            if j == n: 
                j = 0 
            if i < 0: 
                i = n - 1
        if m[int(i)][int(j)]:
            j = j - 2
            i = i + 1
            continue
        else: 
            m[int(i)][int(j)] = num 
            num = num + 1
        j = j + 1
        i = i - 1
    print ("Sum of eggs in each row or column and diagonal : ",int(n*(n*n+1)/2),"\n") 
    for i in range(0, n): 
        for j in range(0, n): 
            print('%2d ' % (m[i][j]),end = '') 
            if j == n - 1:  
                print()

n=int(input("Number of rows of the matrix : "))
matrix(n)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your approach fails when `n` is even. Perhaps you should change your `input` to reflect that. Also -- what is the point of `int` in `m[int(i)][int(j)]`? No need to convert an int to an int. Similarly, `int(n*(n*n+1)/2)` can be replaced by `n*(n*n+1)//2`. No need to go outside ints.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure whether this is what you are looking for, but one solution is to add a random number to each value of the matrix, as this doesn't break the property

> a matrix whose sum of each row, column or diagonal elements are equal.

Here is how you could do it:

```
add = random.randint(0, 50)
m = [[v+add for v in row] for row in m]
```

---

Moreover, you can rotate and add two magic squares without loosing their property. Therefore, you can rotate the magic square you have and add it to the original. This can add some nonlinearity to the results.

```
def rotate(m): # 90 degrees counter clockwise
    return [[m[j][i] for j in range(len(m))] for i in range(len(m[0])-1, -1, -1)]
# add the matrix with its rotated version
m = list(map(lambda e: [sum(x) for x in zip(*e)], zip(m, rotate(m))))
```

I hope this helps!